What is the way to test Google assistant integrated android app?
I have tried to test Google Assistant with my Android app.
I have been using Android studio version Android Studio Ladybug | 2024.2.1 Patch 1.
In Google Assistant Docs one and only way to test the app is installing the Google Assistant Plugin and test it. But that plugin is only available till Android Studio Hedgehog | 2023.1.1 version and later it discontinued. And I could not downgrade the Android Studio due to my project. So what should I do for test the app with Google Assistant Integration?
Added shortcut.xml to the res folder in project.
<?xml version ="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shortcuts xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <capability android:name="actions.intent.OPEN_APP_FEATURE">
        <intent
            android:action="android.intent.action.VIEW"
            android:targetPackage="com.dmr.test"
            android:targetClass="com.dmr.test.MainActivity">
            <parameter
                android:name="feature"
                android:key="feature"/>
        </intent>
    </capability>
</shortcuts>

Added a meta data under activity in AndroidManifest.xml .
  <activity
            ....
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.shortcuts"
                android:resource="@xml/shortcuts" />
  </activity>


There isn't any other way to test the Google* Assistant integration end-to-end. You can install another supported version of Studio without downgrading the main version you use. See How to install multiple Android studio with different versions on same PC?
*You could write your own test Assistant app to test it, but that would be quite a lot of work.
